# Telegram and auto reply with PHP

Tags: php, telegram

I'd like to create a script in PHP that, when a user write to my account from 23:00 to 07:00AM, my account autoreply with: "Try contact me later".

I don't want to use a BOT, i need this script is triggered based on messages incoming on my user telegram.

Is it possible?

I know that with BOT i can set a webhook.
But using normal API for the user, how can I intercept this? Is there a webhook also for this?

I don't find any starting guides or tips to start with this.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to manage your "account" with PHP, you can use https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto. This library can be used to easily interact with Telegram without the bot API, just like the official apps.

Comment: Thank I found it. Do you know some hosting (free) to test some little script... An hosting that support server2server requests.?